# BootstrapValidator with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, ckeditor

I'm trying to do the validation of "CKEditor" using "BootstrapValidator".

Something like in the example here: **[LINK](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/ckeditor/)**

Unfortunately, no way I can make to make it work. I tried to update invisible textarea content but it also did not help. 
My attempts:

```
.find('[name="bio"]')
    .ckeditor()
    .editor
// To use the 'change' event, use CKEditor 4.2 or later
.on('change', function () {
    // Revalidate the bio field
    $('#profileForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'bio');
});
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu5mkcwn/2/)**

Comment: It's working fine from their provided source code example: [`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/urbz/pu5mkcwn/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up date your CKEditor first
add it

`<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/basic/adapters/jquery.js"></script>`

then check it. it may usefull